# How would I go about making this IPTABLE rule for every ip and not just one?

Tags: linux, iptables

```
iptables -I PREROUTING -t nat -p udp -s 192.168.0.62 --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 23.21.182.24
```

Instead of 192.168.0.62 I'd like to set that as a global rule, EVERY ip that needs dns should attempt to use 23.21.182.24 first.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make something like this:

```
iptables -I PREROUTING -t nat -p udp -s 0.0.0.0/0 --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 23.21.182.24
```

It simply defines a `0.0.0.0` IP with a netmask of `0`, that is basically any IP. You may also make it more elegant by defining variables at the start of your script, like that:

```
IPTABLES='/sbin/iptables'
UNIVERSE='0.0.0.0/0'
MYPORT='53'
MYIP='23.21.182.24'
.....
$IPTABLES -I PREROUTING -t nat -p udp -s $UNIVERSE --drop $MYPORT -j DNAT --to-destination $MYIP
```

This will make your iptables management more flexible and easier to maintain/update.
Check a neat example of iptables scripts [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/IP-Masquerade-HOWTO/stronger-firewall-examples.html).

Comment: Why not omit "-s" at all?

Comment: I am not sure if it is ok or not. But even so, I would still like this explicit representation. Things that we usually assume to be obvious or omit them as defaults, may later backfire as nasty bugs...